# consumption with has or have?

Tags: have

I know that "consumption" is a mass word. But my question is:
In sentence: Water and electricity consumption in the hotels HAS FALLEN or HAVE FALLEN? Which option should I use.

Comment: It could go either way, depending on whether electricity and water consumption are independent or necessarily linked together. After all, _water and electricity consumption_ comes from Conjunction Reduction on _water consumption and electricity consumption_, which would be plural, and transformations like Conjunction Reduction don't change meaning.

Answer (score -1):

You've already answered your question.

It's a mass word, right?

And *mass words are singular*, right?

So which is right: it *has* fallen or it *have* fallen?

Easy! I think you're there.

Comment: This does not address the core issue, which is how to treat a compound subject. You should read the comment from John Lawler.